# PHPUnit installation into CakePHP - no Autoload.php

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit

I'm stuck with PHPUnit installation to CakePHP.

**What I have:**

- Debian 6
- CakePHP 2.4.6
- PHPUnit 4.0.7

**What I did:**

1. I installed PHPUnit via PEAR as recommened in [CakePHP doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html).
   It somehow installed the phar archive so that I'm able to use
   `phpunit` executable via CLI. CakePHP `test.php` is looking for `PHPUnit/Autoload.php` in PHP `include_path`. But no directory called `PHPUnit` was
   created anywhere.
2. Then I tried `apt-get` with (a little bit) more success: `PHPUnit` directory with the source was created at
   `/usr/share/php/PHPUnit`. I searched the whole machine for `Autoload.php`, but there was none.

What am I doing wrong? Where is my `Autoload.php`?

Comment: See the tip [here](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-phpunit) - that worked for me.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked, thank you @mark! The installation instructions are a little unclear though. You have to actually **rename** the folder you clone, not clone **into** a folder. If it helps somebody...

Comment: But the question remains: why don't the official solutions work?

Answer (score 2):

Autoload.php no longer exists in the 4.x branch. I believe it was added in the 3.5 branch and remains through the 3.7 branch:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.7.37/PHPUnit/Autoload.php

If you want to downgrade, this should work:

```
pear uninstall phpunit/PHPUnit
pear channel-discover pear.symfony.com
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit-3.7.35
```